# Does DataStax OpsCenter support Cassandra 2.2.5?

Tags: cassandra, compatibility, datastax, opscenter

I've having some issues with my Cassandra cluster and I would like to install [OpsCenter Community](http://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-enterprise-visual-admin) in order to debug what's going on.

I've found [this](http://docs.datastax.com/en/upgrade/doc/upgrade/opscenter/opscCompatibility.html) and [this](http://www.planetcassandra.org/opscenter/) pages talking about the compatibility between DataStax OpsCenter and Cassandra, but this don't list Cassandra 2.2.5 (actually I'm using DataStax Cassandra - `dsc 22`).

**My question is:** can I use DataStax OpsCenter (free / community version) within Cassandra 2.2.5? If not, there's an alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the docs you cited indicate that OpsCenter doesn't support any cassandra greater than 2.1.x and the [next version of opscenter (6.x)](http://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/latest/opsc/opscPolicyChanges.html) will only support Datastax Enterprise. I don't know of another visual front-end to cassandra at this time.

Comment: I've found the following tool in the link you provided: https://github.com/hailocab/ctop Seems interesting, but seems to be outdated.